# Converting keyword/string to integer field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a numeric field that got auto-mapped as keyword for some reason, while I'd like it mapped as an integer.

I tried adding a new index with the desired mapping:

```
PUT temp_index/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "num": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then reindexing:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "main_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "temp_index"
  }
}
```

However, when I then look at the new `temp_index`, I still see the values of the "num" field being strings and not integers.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you get when running `GET temp_index`?

Comment: when you are data from one index to another at that time use ingest pipeline convert processor to convert from string to number. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/convert-processor.html

Comment: @SagarPatel do you mean that the mapping only affects how new data, received after the reindexing, is handled?

Comment: @GJ. Yes, you should define field as integer and pass as integer only in your json or document. if you pass as string it will store as astring and not integer. so here you can use ingest pipeline processor to convert string to integer.